# Advantages of varint encoding use by protobuf

Tags: protocol-buffers

What are the advantages of [varint encoding as used in protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding)?  Is it simply that for smallish messages varints waste less space and time than variable size encodings that add sublinear space?

I suppose someone thought about typical or average message sizes when they picked varints for protobuf?  Any public comments on the reasoning?

Comment: I found this talking about varients of varints for example : http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs276/Jeff-Dean-compression-slides.pdf

Comment: What do you mean by "variable size encodings that add sublinear space"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is varint an efficient data representation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24614553/why-is-varint-an-efficient-data-representation)

Comment: Also [How do varints take less space?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61419435).  It's a message size vs. CPU-time tradeoff.  I think I read that protobuf changed to not use varint anymore, since networks are faster and the CPU time to encode / decode is significant.  (Especially without fancy asm instructions like x86 `pext` / `pdep`.)

Answer (score 0):

Varints save space. This is pretty much the only consideration. Imagine how good it would be if your small integers took up only 1 byte instead of 8 every time you sent a gigantic array of integers.